# Загрузка Sliced Sprite из Resources

Tags: unity3d, спрайт

У меня есть Sprite Sheet, разбитый на отдельные изображения с помощью Unity, после того как я разбил эти изображения у них появилось имя "NAME" + "_0/1/2/3/4/5...".

Как их можно загрузить из папки ресурсов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как и любой другой ресурс - `Resources.LoadAll("Path relative to Resources folder")`. Раз мы знаем, что загружаем объекты типа Sprite, то можно явно это указать в `LoadAll`.

В итоге получаем минимальный пример:

```
Sprite[] LoadSpriteSheet() {
     Sprite[] sprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("ExampleFolder/ExampleSpriteSheet");
     return sprites;
 }
```